# Insert and delete geojson object based on conditions in Python

Tags: python, json, geojson

I have a Geojson as follows:

```
data = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "name": "entities",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "Layer": "0",
            "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference",
            "EntityHandle": "3C8",
            "area": "141.81",
            "type": "p",
            "Text": "area:141.81;type:p"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  2721.1572741014097,
                  1454.3223948456648
                ],
                [
                  2720.121847266826,
                  1454.3223948456648
                ],
                [
                  2720.121847266826,
                  1452.6092152478227
                ],
                [
                  2710.5679254269344,
                  1452.6092152478227
                ],
                [
                  2721.1572741014097,
                  1430.1478385206133
                ],
                [
                  2721.1572741014097,
                  1454.3223948456648
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "Layer": "0",
            "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference",
            "EntityHandle": "3CE",
            "area": "44.79",
            "type": "h",
            "Text": "area:44.79;type:h"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  2710.723323781393,
                  1450.3320226620049
                ],
                [
                  2720.0654518264787,
                  1450.3320226620049
                ],
                [
                  2720.0654518264787,
                  1445.537183875705
                ],
                [
                  2710.723323781393,
                  1445.537183875705
                ],
                [
                  2710.723323781393,
                  1450.3320226620049
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "Layer": "0",
            "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference",
            "EntityHandle": "610",
            "name": "706",
            "area": "92.28",
            "type": "o",
            "Text": "name:706;area:92.28;type:o"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  2714.603212251531,
                  1462.7249212430308
                ],
                [
                  2711.7289360797,
                  1462.7249212430308
                ],
                [
                  2711.7289360797,
                  1464.852506681824
                ],
                [
                  2705.7302059101926,
                  1460.6840827804538
                ],
                [
                  2710.567925426934,
                  1454.3223948456637
                ],
                [
                  2710.567925426934,
                  1453.838838298367
                ],
                [
                  2714.603212251531,
                  1453.838838298367
                ],
                [
                  2714.603212251531,
                  1462.7249212430308
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to insert `"name": ""` if `name` does not exist in `properties`, and delete `"Text"` object since it's duplicated, how can I do that in Python? 
Thanks a lot at advance!

Expected result:

```
data = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "name": "entities",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "Layer": "0",
            "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference",
            "EntityHandle": "3C8",
            "name": "",
            "area": "141.81",
            "type": "p"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  2721.1572741014097,
                  1454.3223948456648
                ],
                [
                  2720.121847266826,
                  1454.3223948456648
                ],
                [
                  2720.121847266826,
                  1452.6092152478227
                ],
                [
                  2710.5679254269344,
                  1452.6092152478227
                ],
                [
                  2721.1572741014097,
                  1430.1478385206133
                ],
                [
                  2721.1572741014097,
                  1454.3223948456648
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "Layer": "0",
            "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference",
            "EntityHandle": "3CE",
            "name": "",
            "area": "44.79",
            "type": "h"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  2710.723323781393,
                  1450.3320226620049
                ],
                [
                  2720.0654518264787,
                  1450.3320226620049
                ],
                [
                  2720.0654518264787,
                  1445.537183875705
                ],
                [
                  2710.723323781393,
                  1445.537183875705
                ],
                [
                  2710.723323781393,
                  1450.3320226620049
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "Layer": "0",
            "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference",
            "EntityHandle": "610",
            "name": "706",
            "area": "92.28",
            "type": "o"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  2714.603212251531,
                  1462.7249212430308
                ],
                [
                  2711.7289360797,
                  1462.7249212430308
                ],
                [
                  2711.7289360797,
                  1464.852506681824
                ],
                [
                  2705.7302059101926,
                  1460.6840827804538
                ],
                [
                  2710.567925426934,
                  1454.3223948456637
                ],
                [
                  2710.567925426934,
                  1453.838838298367
                ],
                [
                  2714.603212251531,
                  1453.838838298367
                ],
                [
                  2714.603212251531,
                  1462.7249212430308
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
My solution so far, it seems works.

```
import json
features = data["features"]

for i in features:
    d = i["properties"]
    if "name" not in d:
        d["name"] = ""
    if i["properties"]["Text"] is not None:
        del i["properties"]["Text"]
```

I define it as a function, but in some cases I get an error as follows. Does someone know how to fix it? Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-8e3095f67c57>", line 138, in <module>
    modify_geojson(output_file)
  File "<ipython-input-1-8e3095f67c57>", line 102, in modify_geojson
    if i["properties"]["Text"] is not None:
KeyError: 'Text'
```

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks, I’m going to try and update.

Comment: I answered my question, please check, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far, it seems works.

```
import json
features = data["features"]

for i in features:
    d = i["properties"]
    if "name" not in d:
        d["name"] = ""
    if i["properties"]["Text"] is not None:
        del i["properties"]["Text"]
```

I define it as a function, but in some cases I get an error as follows. Does someone know how to fix it? Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-8e3095f67c57>", line 138, in <module>
    modify_geojson(output_file)
  File "<ipython-input-1-8e3095f67c57>", line 102, in modify_geojson
    if i["properties"]["Text"] is not None:
KeyError: 'Text'
```

Answer (score 0):

In each property 'Text' is only present once. Please explain where it's duplicated?

Comment: Sorry I mean content of `Text` duplicate with other elements. For example, `"Text": "area:141.81;type:p"` and `"area": "141.81",  "type": "p"`.